# Design token to access Logo in LWC which is setup under Login and Registration of Experience Cloud

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, css3, design-tokens

Is there any design token available to access the logo configured in community administration?

> Workspace -> Administation -> Login & Registration

need to access in registration form build via lwc component, so that it should in sync with the login form.

Basically, I'm implementing a custom registration form to support approvals before actual user creation. however standard login form is still in place.

Now the problem is, on the login form the logo can be configured via admin settings and it should be in sync with the registration form as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Design Tokens in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/335582/using-design-tokens-in-lwc)

Comment: Hey @arut --lwc-brandLogoImage provides the logo setup on the theme level in builder.
But I need to access the logo setup under the login and registration page...

Comment: Ok. I guess that may not have been exposed as it isn't listed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_standard_communities.htm)

Comment: In my experience, you have to override the CSS in the Theme CSS to change the Login pages...find the containing class, and then add style changes there, often with the !important tag, which isn't ideal

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC the context is different, I wanna access the URL of the logo setup under login and registration in the administration of experience cloud site.

Comment: @arut any workaround to access it via apex? I noticed it uses documents to store the logo...

Comment: Using apex to fetch it might be an overkill since you will end up introducing a round trip to server. Instead, you can upload the same logo as static resource and use it in the lightning components. What is the actual use case you are trying to address? If you can improve the question, there might be other solutions possible,

Comment: I'm implementing a custom registration form but leveraging the standard login form. so the registration form logo should be in sync with what we have on the login form. and the logo is configurable via administration settings